# How to add other goals as dependencies for a custom maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Maven. However, it only makes sense to run my plugin after running `mvn compile` and `mvn test-compile`. How can I ensure that these goals are run before my plugin's goals?

Below are the current annotation parameters I'm using, but they don't seem to have the intended effect.

```
@Mojo(name = "testplugin",
      defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.TEST,
      requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST)
```

Answer (score -1):

There's another annotation `@Execute` (https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) that can be used for this purpose. In this particular case, you need to add the following annotation:

```
@Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.TEST_COMPILE,
         goal = "test-compile")
```